# MVC Packages.config can be removed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

I am migrating a project from ASP.NET `WebForms` to `MVC`. The new solution will work on existing pages, `ASPX`, while the new functionality will be implemented using MVC.

So the code changes have been achieved. I understand MVC includes NuGet package and am seeing **packages.config file**  also understood it helps to keep track of version but right now am not interested in using it ( feeling it's taking extra space ).

So if i remove **packages.config** from solution will it harm my MVC application?

Comment: Have you tried removing the packages.config and re building your solution? You will get the errors there only if any..Just try once :)Note : Take a backup first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't, **please**!

I'm sure that you can live with that extra 2-3kb in your project for now.

`NuGet` does a lot of things for you and you will end up loving it in time.

PS: Yes, things will break. Maybe not right away, but they will eventually when you try to install/update a package.

If you do not want to have the packages folder (containing the library packages) in source control, *it is OK to have the folder ignored*. This is safe because you can configure `Visual Studio` to *automatically download the missing packages* when you compile the project. It does this based on the **packages.config** file.

To enable this you have to go in **Options -> NuGet Package Manager** and check the two check-boxes found there.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. But we are using TFS and each time we shelve or unshelved the package folder gets included is it necessary ???